# How to reinitialize eth0 connection without rebooting my system?

Tags: linux, lan, knoppix

I've got a problem when I unplug and then plug in LAN cable, the `eth0` connection stops working, also LAN LED is off.

If I restart the system, LAN connection is normal.

This happens only to onboard LAN port. LAN ports on NIC adapters don't have this issue.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots aren't funny, use textual copy-paste.

Comment: Edit the question with `lspci -nn` line of your `eth0` controller. Find the driver, and google to see if there are known bugs. Test from bottom up: Use `ethtool` to see if the hardware recognizes the link. Use `ip link set eth0 down` and `... up` to manually toggle the link. Etc. My money is on driver bug ...

Comment: Kernels from 4.14.3 on have a bug in the e1000e driver... What version are you using?

Comment: @peterh sorry, pc is not connected to internet and I didn't have flash drive by that time.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `ifdown` then `ifup` or use `NetworkManager`